# Reference to a FOSS project building desktop Google Docs client

Tags: client, google-docs, hybrid

I'm excited about desktop Google Docs client. I found a project using Adobe AIR which imitates Mozilla Prism. That didn't impress me at all. Do you have any pointer to a FOSS project building desktop Google Docs client?

If there are none, if you were to build, how would you do?

Answer (score 1):

“Exciting” things like clipboard/dnd integration, offline, upload integration would mostly come from quality html5 support + some userscripts if google docs doesn't make use of non-portable features yet. Pick a browser with good html5 support, write userscripts, bundle it.